Laravel Task Scheduler OnOneServer Method - Does it work well with cache:clear
I currently have laravel task scheduler command with OnOneServer method . I found out that the entries of the scheduler are saved in the redis cache connection and it creates a mutex to prevent it from running.
Will the cache entry be deleted with cache:clear? I usually run php artisan cache:clear with deployment and I need to make sure that php artisan cache:clear doesn't create problems with this option.
